# No sound playing DVD in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, dvd, windows-media-player

When opening a DVD VOB file in Windows Media Player, no sound can be heard. When opening the same file in Windows Live Photo Gallery, sound is ok.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [ac3filter](http://ac3filter.net/) a try, it seemed to do the job for [numerous others](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistaapps/thread/cce3e9d1-4bac-4b78-8ea2-aa05e07ad2e2), hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: It worked, but could you explain why? It is probably related to other codecs I have installed, because this all worked fine on the same machine at an earlier stage.

Comment: I'm assuming the other installed codecs took precedence over the old ones which worked. ac3 is just taking their place again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on an old laptop. No sound from DVDs playing in Media Player. Also when playing in PowerDVD, the video and audio were very choppy or stuttering. Tried the AC3filter codecs, and all the tweaking of various audio and video settings, no luck. Tried the DMA versus PIO configs as well, no luck.

Solution: Uninstalled PowerDVD by cyberlink and installed WinDVD 4.0, and now my DVD's play great through WinDVD and also Windows Media Player. Hope this helps to keep someone from pulling their hair out like I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using all-in-one (universal) multimedia codecs like [k-lite code pack](http://www.codecguide.com/) its free and easy to install, it auto-configures for most users with optimum performance.